# How to get application.yaml file after cloning repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, figaro-ruby

I have computer A and computer B. I have created an application.yaml file in a Rails application using the Figaro gem on computer A. Then, I cloned the repository from computer B into my local environment and noticed I am missing the application.yaml file.

Is there any way to recover this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `config/application.yml` is not included in the repository for security

The [README](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#getting-started) say:

> ... This creates a commented config/application.yml file and adds it to your .gitignore ...

The idea is to not have passwords, api key and other in the repository.

You have to write the `configuration.yml` file in each computer you have your sistem.